# Dragging 2 elements iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

Please find below my code for dragging 2 elements in the same UI, but seems not working for 2, when I started with one element everything was ok.

When I added second element I have this error in app delegate:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Do you have guys better practice ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 4 - 100, self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 50, 200, 100))
    let label2 = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 1 - 200, self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 50, 200, 100))
    label.text = "Drag me!"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    label2.text = "drag me2!"
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(label2)

    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged"))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    label.userInteractionEnabled = true


    let gesture2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: ("wasDragged2"))
    label2.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
    label2.userInteractionEnabled = true


}

func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    print("was dragged")

}

func wasDragged2(gesture2: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    print("was draged2")



}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action selectors `"wasDragged"` and `"wasDragged2"` are wrong. Those are not the names of your functions. The names of your functions are `"wasDragged:"` and `"wasDragged2:"` (notice the colon at the end of each string name).

Comment: And see my book, to learn what the Objective-C name of a Swift method is: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_selectors

Comment: The correct solution now (which wasn't available when this answer was written) is to use `#selector(wasDragged(_:))` and `#selector(wasDragged2(_:))`. The compiler will complain if the methods don't exist, the compiler will generate the correct Objective-C selectors, and Xcode will offer autocompletions inside the `#selector(...)` form.